# CF Python micoservices application(s) with common local python module(s)

Tags: python, flask, cloud-foundry

I'm writing a CF microservices group of apps in python/flask. There are 6 applications total. All of these share a couple of local python modules.

I can't figure out a decent way to manage these modules such that on each 'cf push' of an app, I get a the current versions of these modules to be included.

I can, of course, use a wrapper for the 'cf push' to copy the modules into a ./local/ directory. This seems like a bit of a hack however.

I don't think it matters, but, all of these apps and modules are in a single GitHub repo.

Quick update: I am currently copying the module dirs into each dir just prior to cf push, then, cleaning up these copies. It's a hack, but, I had to get these apps running. I'd still love to hear from anyone with a better way to handle this.

Comment: Are you using setuptools? If you can `pip install`, you can follow the process to "vendor" your dependencies. The Python buildpack will incorporate vendor'd libraries in just like other libraries. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#vendoring. The vendor'd libraries don't need to be publicly available though, as they get pushed up with your app.

Comment: Daniel, that looks like a winner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Python library is using setuptools, then you should be able to `pip install` it. If you can `pip install` it then you can follow the Cloud Foundry process to "vendor" your dependencies.

The Python buildpack will incorporate all vendor'd libraries into the application just like other libraries downloaded from the Internet. See [the docs for the process to vendor a library](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#vendoring). Your vendor'd libraries don't need to be publicly available though, as they are simply pushed up with the rest of your app.